# Is there a way to recognise class associations of java code using ANTLR grammar?

Tags: java, antlr4

I would like to use ANTLR for static code analysis and with that I'm looking for a way to recognise references within a class to another class. Possibly something like this:

```
class A {
  private B myReferenceToB;

  A(){
    this.myReferenceToB = new B();

  }
  public method(){
    B refrenceFromMethod = new B();
  }

  private method2(){
    B refrenceFromPrivateMethod = new B();
  }

}

class B {}
```

Any of these cases would mean, that class A and B are in some sort related to each other and I'm trying to figure out how to recognise this in ANTLR.

I did some search and went through some tutorials, but I didn't find anything that would move me in the right direction.

Using this grammar: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java/java

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Antlr4 doesn't implement semantics, but it does generate two types of tree walkers for you to implement semantics. You can also achieve what you want using an XPath2 engine with the parse tree represented in a DOM. So, you can write something like `//classDeclaration/concat(./identifier/IDENTIFIER/text(), " ", ./classBody/classBodyDeclaration/memberDeclaration/fieldDeclaration/typeType/classOrInterfaceType/identifier/IDENTIFIER/text())`. The XPath engine within selected Antlr4 runtimes is sub-version-1 XPath. If you write the XPath expressions, you can use that to manually write a tree walker.

Comment: Okay, that sounds quite interesting. I'll give it a go after I understand that part of ANTLR. Thank you!

Comment: I wrote an example that demonstrates the use of xpaths on the parse tree "solving" this problem. https://github.com/kaby76/so71155976

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to figure out how to recognise this in ANTLR

That is not what ANTLR will recognise. ANTLR does not tell you if input is semantically correct (the Java grammar will parse input like `boolean q = 42;` just fine).

ANTLR will create a lexer and parser for you, and the means to traverse the parse tree of your input (a `.java` source file, in your case) using a listener or visitor. What happens then is up to you.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, that ANTLR will not give me a semantical answer. I'm trying to figure out, how could I walk the tree that ANTLR gives me and possibly figure out, if there is a reference for class B in class A and so on. But I don't really know how could I approach this. From your answer I assume I should go through the parse tree and write the logic of recognising references outside of ANTLR? I was hoping that there could be an easier way.

Comment: Sorry, there is no easier answer. "recognising references outside of ANTLR" is not easily answered by only looking at a tree structure: it needs knowledge of the semantics of the language. ANTLR only gives you a tree.

Comment: "From your answer I assume I should go through the parse tree and write the logic of recognising references outside of ANTLR?", yes.